# Access column in a laravel pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table

When my new app, gets to this line:

```
$user_game = ( $user->games->count() == 0 ) ? $this->start( $game, $user ) : $user->pivot->data;
```

I get the following error:

**ErrorException (E_NOTICE)**

Trying to get property of non-object

It looks like `$user->pivot->data` is not a property in my pivot table.

In my User class I have:

```
public function games(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( Game::class )
        ->withPivot( [ 'data', 'finished' ] );
}
```

In my Game class I have:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( User::class )
        ->withPivot( [ 'data', 'finished' ] );
}
```

Attach method is working perfect, detach mode works too.

Am I missing something? For me it looks like it was done exactly as I should.

Comment: Can you please just dd($user->pivot); and let us know what does it return ?

Answer (score 0):

If the code changed from

```
->withPivot( [ 'data', 'finished' ] );
```

to

```
->withPivot('data', 'finished');
```

> When working with a many-to-many relationship, the save method accepts an array of additional intermediate table attributes as its second argument:

```
App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)